# MySQL Join tables on weekday+hour of timestamp, count per table

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, count, timestamp

I have a couple of tables with exact the same structure. They contain data from forms filled in at the entrance of a yearly event. One of the fields in these tables is a `DATETIME` with the date and time of the entry.

For statistical purposes, I am trying to compare the amount of entries per hour of each year. Of course, I could run separate queries for each table and put them together in PHP. But I think it should also be possible in one single query. However, I cannot figure out how to build up a correct query.

This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT
    WEEKDAY(P3.AddedOn) Day,
    HOUR(P3.AddedOn) Hour,
    COUNT(P3.AddedOn) Entries2013,
    COUNT(P2.AddedOn) Entries2012
FROM Event2013 P3
LEFT JOIN Event2012 P2
    ON WEEKDAY(P3.AddedOn) = WEEKDAY(P2.AddedOn)
        AND HOUR(P3.AddedOn) = HOUR(P2.AddedOn)
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(P3.AddedOn), WEEKDAY(P2.AddedOn), HOUR(P3.AddedOn), HOUR(P2.AddedOn)
```

But this query yields some strange results with too large numbers and the same numbers in the Entries2012 and Entries2013 columns. It adds up some data, but I cannot figure out exactly which.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

--

Solved with subqueries:

```
SELECT
    P2.Day,
    P2.Hour,
    P2.Entries Entries2012,
    P3.Entries Entries2013
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            WEEKDAY(AddedOn) Day,
            HOUR(AddedOn) Hour,
            COUNT(1) AS Entries
        FROM Event2012
        GROUP BY Day, Hour
    ) P2
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            WEEKDAY(AddedOn) Day,
            HOUR(AddedOn) Hour,
            COUNT(1) AS Entries
        FROM Event2013
        GROUP BY Day, Hour
    ) P3
        ON P2.Day = P3.Day
            AND P2.Hour = P3.Hour
```

--

Now also with some kind of MySQL FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT
    Day,
    Hour,
    Entries2012,
    Entries2013
FROM (
    SELECT
        (CASE P2.Day
            WHEN 4 THEN "Fr"
            WHEN 5 THEN "Sat"
            WHEN 6 THEN "Sun"
            ELSE P2.Day
            END) AS Day,
        P2.Hour,
        COALESCE(P2.Entries, 0) Entries2012,
        COALESCE(P3.Entries, 0) Entries2013
    FROM (
        SELECT
            WEEKDAY(AddedOn) Day,
            HOUR(AddedOn) Hour,
            COUNT(1) AS Entries
        FROM Event2012
        GROUP BY Day, Hour) P2
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            WEEKDAY(AddedOn) Day,
            HOUR(AddedOn) Hour,
            COUNT(1) AS Entries
        FROM Event2013
        GROUP BY Day, Hour) P3
    ON P2.Day = P3.Day
        AND P2.Hour = P3.Hour
    UNION SELECT
        (CASE P3.Day
            WHEN 4 THEN "Fr"
            WHEN 5 THEN "Sat"
            WHEN 6 THEN "Sun"
            ELSE P3.Day
            END) AS Day,
        P3.Hour,
        COALESCE(P2.Entries, 0) Entries2012,
        COALESCE(P3.Entries, 0) Entries2013
    FROM (
        SELECT
            WEEKDAY(AddedOn) Day,
            HOUR(AddedOn) Hour,
            COUNT(1) AS Entries
        FROM Event2012
        GROUP BY Day, Hour) P2
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT
            WEEKDAY(AddedOn) Day,
            HOUR(AddedOn) Hour,
            COUNT(1) AS Entries
        FROM Event2013
        GROUP BY Day, Hour) P3
    ON P2.Day = P3.Day
        AND P2.Hour = P3.Hour
    WHERE P2.Hour IS NULL) AS tmp
ORDER BY Day, Hour
```

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN says that you intend to take all entries from P3 and expect that some of them won't match in P2. If P3 is your base table (and you look for possible matches in another table), you only have to group by P3 columns.

```
SELECT P3.Day Day, P3.Hour Hour, Entries2013, Entries2012 
FROM (
SELECT   
    WEEKDAY(AddedOn) Day,
    HOUR(AddedOn) Hour,
    COUNT(AddedOn) Entries2013
    GROUP BY Day, Hour
FROM Event2013) P3
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
    WEEKDAY(AddedOn) Day,
    HOUR(AddedOn) Hour,
    COUNT(AddedOn) Entries2012
    GROUP BY Day, Hour
FROM Event2012) P2
ON P3.DAY = P2.DAY
AND P3.Hour = P2.Hour
GROUP BY P3.Day, P3.Hour;
```

Also, using WEEKDAY means you sum all Mondays, Tuesdays etc in the given year and then get hourly summaries from that. If you want to get daily summaries (where the day is the day of the year), you should use DAYOFYEAR i/o WEEKDAY.

Comment: I added the extra columns in the `GROUP BY` later. Unfortunately, omitting them does not change the result.

Comment: The grouping by `WEEKDAY` is on purpose (but maybe wrong?). The event takes place once a year on a Saturday and a Sunday. The result I am looking for should allow me to compare the amount of entries on for example the Saturday between 9 AM and 10 AM of both years.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UNION statement:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

This combines queries from two tables.